# Share Link with Picture URI on Facebook in Wp7

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I am using the following parameters to Post a Link along with the picture uri to Facebook. But the thumbnail picture gets cropped. How can i solve this?

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();          
parameters.Add("link", link);
parameters["picture"] = picUri;
parameters.Add("caption", "");
parameters.Add("message", "haha");
parameters.Add("name", Title);
client.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
```

I have attached the original image and the image shared.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "action" parameter . The Image will not be cropped. Please refer this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

```
        Dictionary<string, string> action1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        action1.Add("name", "View on");
        action1.Add("link", link);

        parameters.Add("actions", action1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should resize the image to make it a perfect square, e.g. 250x250, so Facebook renders it correctly. Otherwise, Facebook will always crop the image.

Comment: :but the same Picture url is working fine when we shared the image through ios or android phone.

Comment: @MuditBajpai but HOW is it being shared in android or iOS?

Comment: @MattLacey The same code works fine in WP8. But only link is clickable, where as in this above code entire box is clickable. What are we missing? The link shared contains the same picture as picUri. Will it be replacing the picUri?